# Dialog window change events in Vaadin

Tags: event-handling, vaadin, vaadin7

In Vaadin 7, has anyone implemented dialog window change events in addition to View change events? I'm wondering how to get dialogs to trigger change events the same way views do with the ViewChangeListener.

I'm thinking of using the Google Event Bus, but I figured I'd ask around first.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin has an event routing mechanism defined in the com.vaadin.event package. You should start there.

A few links to get you started:

https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/package-summary.html
http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/9781849515221/ch05lvl1sec24